# Send email to culprits email-ext

Tags: svn, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

I want to send email to developers who commited something in the SVN repo in the Jenkins Pipeline.

I have a try and catch (similiar to this [try-catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948606/jenkins-notifying-error-by-sending-mail-in-pipeline-former-known-as-workflow) and this [try-catch2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793687/email-ext-and-workflow-pipeline-some-tokens-not-being-expanded)):

```
catch(Exception e) {
    String error = "${e}"
    emailext body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT', 
    subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT', 
    to: 'cronaldo'
}
```

If anything goes wrong with the build it will send an email to cronaldo (for example; cristiano.ronaldo@hisdomain.com). But this is hardcoded into the catch. I want to have something like get_commiters_id (`to: get_commiters_id`) where it gets the id based on a change in the SVN repo by one or many users.

Is there a way to get the user_id from jenkins? I know that the email-ext plugin has a `$default_recipients` which sends an email to the user who started the build. The email should be sent when it triggers if something goes wrong.

I guess what I want is the Culprits.

Comment: I am confused . . where is your try and catch ?? In jenkins master config ? In jenkins job config ?

Comment: @gaoithe in my jenkins job conifg

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Email-extension plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin),

It has the ability to send Email to Culprits in his advanced options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Set an Email-Ext trigger in your jenkins job with Culprits as Send To.

jenkins jobs - under Post-build Actions - in Editable Email Notification (Email-Ext section) - choose Advanced. Add or edit a trigger. (You can see trigger options and Send To options as in screen shot from answer by @Shachar Hamuzim Rajuan ) Choose Culprits as the Send To.